# How do i put dataSnapshot into a HashMap and Iterate Firebase Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to turn a DataSnapshot object to HashMap then iterate it for accessing latitude longitude and avatar values for each player. Because after this i will use those values to render markers on map.

[db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QJa4.png)

Another question is is it possible to exclude users itself from the query ? 
I mean is it possible to write mydb.child("map").child("players").notequalto(username).addValueEventList...
Or do  i have to exclude it with code  after pulling the data?

```
    mydb.child("map").child("players").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                HashMap<String,Object> players= new HashMap();
for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                players.put(childSnapshot.getKey(), childSnapshot.getValue());
            }
                    Log.d("players",dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());





            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

output:

```
 D/players: {lifesuxtr={lat=40.8901741, long=29.3772963, avatar =petyr}, lastpeony={lat=40.89, long=29.37, avatar=dino}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the `map` node is a direct child of your Firebase database root, to get those values, please the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference playersRef = rootRef.child("map").child("players");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Map<Double, Double> players = new HashMap<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            double lat = ds.child("lat").getValue(Double.class);
            double long = ds.child("long").getValue(Double.class);
            Log.d("TAG", lat + " / " + long);
            players.put(lat, long);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
    }
};
playersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

The output will be:

```
40.89 / 29.37
40.89 / 29.37
```

Having there values, you can now add your markers. And answering to your question, no, you cannot use negation in a query. There is no `notEqualTo()` method in Firebase.

Comment: @olajide Thanks olajide!

Comment: What the OP requested is very simple and you have done the most part. We just need put the data into HashMap. I have added few lines to the answer

Comment: @olajide Edit approved but edit once more to get the declaration of the ` players` map outside the for loop.

Comment: `long` is a keyword in java that is used to store 64-bit integer (Java primitive type) value. That was why i renamed the variable to `longi`

Comment: @olajide There's no need for that. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Alex Mamo datasnapshot does not return a Map, it returns a dataSnapshot.. try passing dataSnapshot to a function which requires a Map and see for yourself...  although as per the question no need to create the map because you can itereate over a dataSnapshot directly - but a dataSnapshot is not the same as a Map as you have given in your answer - please correct it...

Comment: @DragonFire Oh yes, just removed the first part of my answer. Thanks